# Kentico 10 ASPX + Portal many-to-many relationships in repeater

Tags: c#, kentico

I'm largely a front-end developer and have only rudimentary C# knowledge, but I have successfully used Kentico to build several large websites and am familiar with many of its tools. I'm most familiar with the ASPX Templates model of Kentico development.

I'm working on a website where I need to establish a many-to-many relationship between a product and a product use. From a content-entry standpoint, this has been relatively easy to set up, using the built-in "related pages" property with a pair of custom page types. And when I'm on a single product page, I can output the product properties as well as the related page properties. But if I want to output all the products to a page via a repeater, I'm unable to also output the related pages at the same time. It seems like it will require a repeater within a repeater in some fashion, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do this. Or maybe I'm completely wrong. Thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: So in a single repeater you want to output both current products and related products?

Answer (score 0):

You can use more approaches to achieve it, however this one is from Kentico documentation when using ASCX transformation you can register other repeater control for displaying related pages:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="CMSRepeater1" runat="server" ClassNames="CMS.News" Path="/%" TransformationName="cms.news.preview" RelationshipName="isrelatedto" RelationshipWithNodeGUID="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you CAN load a repeater within a repeater, the ASCX transformations are ASCX so you can put the  control in it and configure it like the below:

```
    <script runat="server">     
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)     {  
        // Adjust repeater
        rptSubTimes.Path = Eval<string>("NodeAliasPath") + "/%";
        //Reload
        rptSubTimes.ReloadData(true);     
    } 
</script>


    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="rptSubTimes" runat="server" TopN="1" ClassNames="FS.EventDateTime" Columns="EventDTTime" OrderBy="EventDTTime DESC" TransformationName="FS.EventDateTime.HomeEndTime" />
```

However, this may not be the best approach, and you may want to look into use a Custom Query (Repeater with Custom Query) to get the data, or a "Universal viewer with custom query" webpart in order to generate a multi-level Hierarchy transformation based on your query.

Additionally you can use a Macro transformation (text/xml) and use the Macro's "ApplyTransformation" to apply a transformation to a sub item.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through using Kentico repeater alone however there would be sone content entry effort to establish right relationships among various products.

Luckily I wrote an article about it sometime ago and you may check it here.

[Showing Related Content through a repeater](http://www.bodhitreelabs.com/Blog/January-2016/Related-Documents-through-a-Repeater)